# VNDetectBarcodesRequest unable to identify Codabar and GS1DataBar

Tags: swift, barcode

Given to revision2 and revision3 is not working at this moment, I'm currently using VNDetectBarcodesRequestRevision1 as workaround to detect barcodes with photo image, however it not manage to identify Codabar and GS1Databar symbology, is this a version limit or just a bug?